# How to convert a .java files to UML diagrams under Fujaba?

Tags: java, uml

Please can anyone show me how to convert a .java to UML diagram under Fujaba?

Here is the main site of the program: http://www.fujaba.de/

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you loose your time with Fujaba ?
You have Topcased, Boul and Papyrus which are open source and can create diagrams from java code.
The best reverse engineering tool if you have a budget is Omondo EclipseUML. 
This tool is for advanced and heavy java project developped by a team working together. If a single developer then open source is sufficient.